# NullPointerException depending the device with createStatement

Tags: java, android, sql-server, nullpointerexception

I want to connect to a SQL Server with Android.

This is my code:

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);

try{
Statement ps = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery ("select * from cliente");
.....
}
catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Everything is Ok if I run the application in a Samsung Galaxy Ace, but if I want to run it in another device, this is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and this error is in line:

```
Statement ps = conn.createStatement();
```

I don't know why depending the device this runs or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Statement ps = db.conn.createStatement();
```

This should be

```
Statement ps = conn.createStatement();
```

Here the value of db is `null` i guss, and so you are getting `NullPointerException` from this line of code.
Please let me know in case of any concern.

EDIT:

If db is not present in your code then put a Sysout like:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);
Sysout.out.Println("value of conn is "+conn);
```

And check the value of conn. This is null as per my understanding.

FYI:

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);
```

These tow lines must me inside a try/catch block.

Comment: Sorry, "db." is not in the code, I don't know why is here. The problem is why in some devices it works and in another it doesn't

Comment: If db is not in your code and also the variable conn is not present in db object then you will get compile time issue and not NullPointerexception in runtime.

Comment: I've changed the answer, db. should not be here, everything is in the same class, like is in the code now. Sorry

Comment: Yes, lines are in a try/catch block. I've tried to simplify the code.

Comment: have u checked the value of conn by giving a sysout?

Comment: I don't know why logcat and console don't show me de value of this sysout

Comment: Value of conn is: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2@40568d98